# Can getstream.io be hosted in Australia?

Tags: getstream-io

My company has regulatory constraints that require all data to be hosted in Australia. Are there any plans to offer getstream.io hosted in the ap-southeast-2 AWS region?

Cheers
Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but running a full cluster for 1 company is expensive. Contact sales at getstream dot io to learn more.

Best,
Thierry

Comment: I am interested as well. Any news?